# Светлохвойный (лес): слитно или через дефис? Какое правило здесь применимо?

Tags: сложные-прилагательные

Думала от словосочетания светлая хвоя, поэтому слитно... В одном тексте (энциклопедия) встретила "светло-хвойный" и "темнохвойный" Где ошибка?

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: **светлохвойный** (ср. **[темнохвойный](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)**)

См. **Бешенкова Е.В., Иванова О.Е., Чельцова Л.К. "Объяснительный русский орфографический словарь-справочник" (2015)**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

**Светлохвойный,** написание слитное.

Почему? Думаете, в основе лежит сочетание ***светлая хвоя*** (подчинительная связь)? А вот и нет. Это **термин**, а термины пишутся в большинстве случаев слитно.

По определению, **лес светлохвойный** — лес, образованный преимущественно **светолюбивыми** породами: сосной или лиственницей. Также это понятие связано с густотой произрастания. Обычно в лесу темнохвойных пород часто полумрак, причиной этому — густота растительности. А сосновые леса — прозрачные, наполненные светом. А вот молодая хвоя и у сосны скорее **темно-зеленая**.

**Итак, термины пишем только слитно.** А если не термин? Правило вот есть для **дефисного** написания **в предыдущем ответе:** "Прилагательные, обозначающие оттенки качества (преимущественно цвета или вкуса). Это правило распространяется и на любые **индивидуально-авторские образования, обозначающие сочетания признаков.** Такие сложные прилагательные широкоупотребляются в художественной и публицистической речи".

А если у меня как раз индивидуально-авторское образование со словом "светлый", например: ***Лес сосновый, светло-хвойный, солнцем залитой***..." Хвоя здесь светлая, золотистая, потому что это эффект солнечного освещения, вот я и хочу это изобразить в словесном описании.  Что мне, интересно, скажет редактор?

Хотя можно догадаться, что. **Трудно всё-таки быть поэтом.**